# Grep IP address from variable containing file contents outside the if statement

Tags: shell

What I want to do is to extract IP addresses from the filecontent variable outside the if statement:

```
    shift $(($OPTIND - 1)) 
    if [ $1 = "-" ] || [ -z $1 ]; then  

        filecontent=$(cat logfile.log) 
        echo "$filecontent" | grep -E -o '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' # note try this outside the if 
    fi

    echo "$filecontent" | grep -E -o '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
```

Sample from logfile.log:

```
172.16.0.3 - - [31/Mar/2002:19:30:41 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 123 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/2.2.2-2; Linux)"
172.16.0.3 - - [31/Mar/2002:19:30:41 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 - "" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/2.2.2-2; Linux)"
```

The output:

```
grep: Argument list too long
```

So what am I doing wrong?

```
grep -- version
```

The output

```
grep (GNU grep) 2.16
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

Comment: I suspect the `grep: Argument list too long` error is flagging a completely different `grep` invocation - that one only has two arguments...

Comment: In this particular log, the IP address is the first word on each line, so this would suffice: `cut -d" " -f1 logfile.log` -- is that too simple for your needs?

Comment: I have to cat the file in a variable then extract the ip addresses. This cut -d" " -f1 logfile.log  works for me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run for loop, just grep directly to the input file:

```
grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' file
```

**Update:** Even when you file content in a variable you don't need for loop. Just use it like this:

```
filecontent=$(<logfile.log)
echo "$filecontent" | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
```

Comment: Thanks, but dosnt help the output is still the same as i mentioned above

Comment: Can you show a sample of input data from `logfile.log`?

Comment: No not in comment, pls edit your question and provide it there.

Comment: When I run above grep command on your input data I get `172.16.0.3` twice.

Comment: I dont know why its not working for me! is says that the argument is too long, note that it works for me when i have grep from logfile.log but not when i have the file content in variable.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, it works when im in the if sats for if std input is typed, then cat file to the variable ..... 
but as soon im outside and need to grep something form the $filecontent i get the argument too long output.

Comment: If you can provide a code that reproduces the problem then I can only do something otherwise all my tests are working and producing expected results.

Comment: I have updated my question above, now try to extract something from the $filecontent outside the if and see if you get the same problem

Comment: Your question is still showing for loop which I have asked you to eliminate by using my update section code.

Comment: sorry i forget to update it, now the question is updated and looks exactly as my script and still gives that error!

Comment: grep (GNU grep) 2.16
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.

Comment: ok I have 2.18 gnu grep but 2.16 should also be fine. May be your actual log file has some invalid data because I cannot reproduce the problem with this sample data.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts, i will try to find out the problem. Thank you again!